# Is it correct to hand a Service to an Entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I know it's generally considered a bad practice to *inject* Services in an Entity (through a constructor or a setter), and to have the entity keep a reference to it.

But is it ok to transiently hand a Service to an entity when invoking a method?

For example, say I want to version the `name` field of an Entity, and have a `VersionService` create a new version every time `setName()` is called, I could do:

```java
public class Entity
{
    public void setName(String name, VersionService service)
    {
        this.name = name;
        service.addVersion(this, name);
    }
}
```

What I like in this code, is that the `setName()` method can't be called without providing a `VersionService`, thus forcing the desired behavior. It's also easily testable, by mocking the `VersionService`.

I've found an example of this approach in a post on the [double dispatch pattern](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern/) by [Jimmy Bogard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard).

But from some discussions on Stack, I thought that the general consensus was to avoid having any dependency on Services in the Domain Model.

Any thought on the subject?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by Services. Domain Services ? Application Services ? Infrastructure Services ? There are services in all sorts of layers in DDD.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm talking about Domain Services here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But from some discussions on Stack, I thought that the general
>   consensus was to avoid having any dependency on Services in the Domain
>   Model.

As far as *Domain* services are concerned, I'd be curious to know the arguments against using them in entities. Domain services are first class domain objects contained in the ubiquitous language. There are plenty of scenarios where it is justified for logic located in an entity to call logic located in a domain service, just like it would call another entity.

Paragaph 3 in [this article](http://stochastyk.blogspot.fr/2008/05/domain-services-in-domain-driven-design.html) has a good example of this.

Comment: I believe this is exactly right. Domain service is perfectly valid to pass to an entity (or value object). Architecturally, the application service would obtain a reference to the appropriate domain service and pass it to interested entities.

Answer (score 1):

You typically use the domain event to generate the new version:

```java
public class Entity
{
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        DomainEvent.Publish(new MyEntityGotRenamed(Id));
    }
}

public class YourService : ISubscribeOn<MyEntityGotRenamed>
{
     public void Handle(MyEntityGotRenamed domainEvent)
     {
         var entity = repos.Get(domainEvent.Id);
         AddVersion(entity);
     }
}
```

How you subscribe on the events is platform specific.

Do note that `setName` isn't representing a domain action. Should be `Rename` or something else that your client has defined.

Comment: Interesting approach indeed. How do you unit test domain events?

Comment: you unit test that they get generated correctly and that the service handles it properly. (different unit tests)

Comment: So you wouldn't test directly that `setName()` triggers a call to `addVersion()`, but instead test that `setName()` generates a `MyEntityGotRenamed` event, and that the Service reacts to `MyEntityGotRenamed` by calling `addVersion()`?

Comment: yes. That's how I would do it. You could even create a class dedicated for that purpose: `class StoreVersionsFromMyEntityChanges : ISubscribeOn<MyEntityGotRenamed>, ISubscribeOn<DeletedMyEntity>`

Answer (score 1):

The Domain Events approach is good, but it's dependent on using a message driven architecture.

Regardless of that and specifically for the example you gave, I wouldn't pass the service as an argument, because IMO it's not the Entity concern to update other model using the service. The Entity (which probably is an aggregate root) cares only for its own model. The code which calls the Entity may call the Service as well.

However, I think it's ok to pass a service as an argument in order to retrieve some other necessary data (sadly I can't think of an example right now). But most of the time you'd pass the service as a constructor dependency that is you need that service for more than an operation and you can't supply the data as a method argument.

Comment: The link on the double dispatch pattern in my question is a perfect example of the approach you're mentioning (to retrieve necessary data). I understand that my code is slightly different, but what bothers me with what you suggest is that it doesn't enforce the fact that you **can't** call setName() without calling the VersionService. If I use your approach, there is an open door to use my domain model in a wrong way.

Comment: So you want to ensure that both setName and VersionService method are called together? I still wouldn't put that concern in the Entity, they are 2 different things. Probably using the domain events is more clean but that doesn't mean those 2 things are automatically in a transaction.

Comment: Yes, that's a recurring problem in my application: two methods need to be called together on two different objects. I don't want to expose `setName()` alone, and introduce the risk to have it called separately. Also, I'm afraid that my entities will become anemic if all they expose is getters and setters.

Comment: You want a transaction like behavior for operations belonging to different bounded contexts I presume. Probably the best way would be via the domain events i.e message driven architecture but you have to get used to the idea of eventual consistency. NOw if you only need to call methods on different objects but all are part of the same bounded context then you don't really have a problem as the aggregate root can implement that behavior

Comment: Do you mean that the aggregate should contain the versions as well, instead of relying on a Service to maintain them?

Comment: Are the versions a concept that belongs to that bounded context? It's hard to tell stuff withouht knowing lots of details about the Domain. The devil is in the details in DDD more than ever